# Want to get key value from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I want to get all key values in an array. Here I used the keyword `allKeysForObject`. While using `allKeysForObject`, I got value within parenthesis. I want to store value without parenthesis.
Here is my code:

```
dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[dict setValue:@"Hai" forKey:@"1"];
[dict setValue:@"lrd" forKey:@"2"];
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];
NSMutableArray *countryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *keyObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


for(NSString* key in keys) {
    NSString *obj = [dict objectForKey:key];
    [countryArray addObject:obj];

}
for (int i =0; i < [countryArray count]; i++) {
    [keyObjects addObject:[dict allKeysForObject: [countryArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
}

NSLog(@"%@",[keyObjects objectAtIndex:0]);
```

The NSLog value is:

```
2013-11-28 17:12:48.400 Help[6775:c07] (
    1
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem confused to me :|

Comment: why don't you using - (NSArray *)allKeys; method that give you array of all key in NSDictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[keyObjects objectAtIndex:0]);
```

With:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[keyObjects objectAtIndex:0][0]);
```

You are storing in `keyObjects` the value returned by `allKeysForObject:` which is a `NSArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `loop` for getting all key values from `NSDictionary` use `- (NSArray *)allKeys;`
method to do that. It is always good to use given methods than writing our own code to achieve the same.
so replace of the `for loop` with following code...

```
keyObjects = [[dict allKeys]mutableCopy]; // mutableCopy because I think you want it mutable as your array is mutable.
```

**EDIT**

AFA your code concern, your are getting parenthesis because you are storing all keys in keyObjects array as array, that why you can see those parenthesis out there in you log statement. and this is because `allKeysForObject` method returns array of keys related to given object. 
and if you want it to be done in your way here it is...

```
for (int i =0; i < [countryArray count]; i++) {
    [keyObjects addObject:[dict allKeysForObject: [[countryArray objectAtIndex:i]0]]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get all values in an **NSDictionary** using **[dict allValues]**. you dont need to manually iterate the array

```
dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[dict setValue:@"Hai" forKey:@"1"];
[dict setValue:@"lrd" forKey:@"2"];
NSMutableArray *countryArray = [[dict allValues] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *keyObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


for (int i =0; i < [countryArray count]; i++) {
    [keyObjects addObject:[dict  allKeysForObject: [countryArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
}

NSLog(@"%@",[keyObjects objectAtIndex:0][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

While `NSLog`-ing:

Whenever you see `(...)`  it is array.

Whenever you see `{...}` it is dictionary.

So in your case it is shown as `(1)` so this is an array with one object.

Hence you need to do through one level down to retrieve it.

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[keyObjects objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0]); //or
NSLog(@"%@",[keyObjects objectAtIndex:0][0]);
```